# Warning assignment from incompatible pointer type for print the addresses of a matrix

Tags: c

I have to write a code that prints the addresses of a matrix elements. In my understanding, matrix should return a pointer to a pointer, so I attributed it to a double pointer and used a for to print this pointer values (addresses). however, the compiler warns "assignment from incompatible pointer type". I also tried to use *p instead of **p and the compiler warned of the same thing. Why is this so?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int matrix[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int **p;
    p = matrix;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", p+i);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code causes the compiler to output 3 messages:

```
untitled.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled.c:6:24: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
 int matrix[3][3] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
                    ^
                     {    }{    }{    }

untitled.c:8:7: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 p = matrix;
   ^

untitled.c:10:18: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("%d\n", p+i);
             ~^     ~~~
```

also, the code contains several 'magic' numbers (I.E. 3)

The code would be much better, written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define MAX_ROWS 3
#define MAX_COLS 3


int main( void ) 
{
    int matrix[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ] = 
    {
        { 1,2,3 },
        { 4,5,6 },
        { 7,8,9 }
    };

    for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++ ) 
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%p\n", (void*)&matrix[i][j] );
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What are magic numbers? I had put p** as an intermediary because I'm learning pointers and I wanted to test how I attribute a matrix pointer to another pointer. Then I used this other pointer to print the addresses of the matrix's elements. But I still don't get the motive of the warning. Actually, the addresses printed in my code were the same as in yours, even when I used *p instead of **p, so you can see why I'm confused ahhahahhah

Comment: 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Therefore, no intrinsic meaning to the reader of the code.  The technique is to give the 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use that meaningful name throughout the code.  The meaningful name can be supplied via either a `#define` or a `enum`